# Video player breaks down in flutter 2.0 (null safety)

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-video-player, flutter2.0

I want to show a video in my flutter app and like always, I am using the video_player plugin. But for some reason, now that I have migrated to null safety, the video player gives me this error

```
Error: PlatformException(MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED, MEDIA_ELEMENT_ERROR: Format error, The video has been found to be unsuitable (missing or in a format not supported by your browser)., null)


    at Object.createErrorWithStack (http://localhost:59815/dart_sdk.js:5050:12)
    at Object._rethrow (http://localhost:59815/dart_sdk.js:37641:16)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:59815/dart_sdk.js:37637:13)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:59815/dart_sdk.js:37497:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:59815/dart_sdk.js:37503:13)
    at http://localhost:59815/dart_sdk.js:33274:9
```

I am running my code on flutter web, and am using the exact copy paste of the example code, just migrated to null safety. This is my code

```
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(ChapterVideoPlayer());

class ChapterVideoPlayer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChapterVideoPlayerState createState() => _ChapterVideoPlayerState();
}

class _ChapterVideoPlayerState extends State<ChapterVideoPlayer> {
  VideoPlayerController? _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'https://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_20mb.mp4')
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Video Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: _controller!.value.isInitialized
              ? AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: _controller!.value.aspectRatio,
            child: VideoPlayer(_controller!),
          )
              : Container(),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _controller!.value.isPlaying
                  ? _controller!.pause()
                  : _controller!.play();
            });
          },
          child: Icon(
            _controller!.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller!.dispose();
  }
}
```

Am I doing it wrong? Or is there a problem with the plugin. Is there any replacement I can use for the meanwhile? Any help would be very appreciated. Iam using version `^2.1.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED` is just a consequence of another error `net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` (you can see it in the browser console). Because not all SSL certificates cover both the WWW and non-WWW versions of a website by default (as in case with sample-videos.com), you have to remove `www` from url:

```dart
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_20mb.mp4')
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
        setState(() {});
      });
```